# In pyspark 2.1.0, how to update a column with its decimal value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

In pyspark 2.1.0, I have a column that contains scientific notated numbers as strings.

I need to convert them into their decimal equivalent as floats, for example:

```
"-9.469530778005719E-5" --> -0.00009469530778005719
```

For this purpose I use the decimal library:

```
gar_dataframe.withColumn("lat_rep",decimal.Decimal(gar_dataframe.lat_rep))
```

However, this throws the following error:

> TypeError: conversion from Column to Decimal is not supported

Based on this [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn), I should pass a Column expression. But from [this doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column), I do not understand, for my purpose, how I can create a Column expression to achieve my goal.

How can I change this column values ? If not with `withColumn`, could you point me a direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly cast it from `string` to `DecimalType`:

```
df.withColumn('deci', df.lat_rep.cast('decimal(25, 20)')).show(truncate=False)

+---------------------+-----------------------+
|lat_rep              |deci                   |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
|-9.469530778005719E-5|-0.00009469530778005719|
+---------------------+-----------------------+
```